# Issues with variables with html checkbox

Tags: php, html

I've got this code:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>

<FORM action = "respuestas.php" METHOD "post">
1. ¿Cuál es la capital de México?<br>
<INPUT TYPE = "radio" VALUE="nayarit" CHECKED NAME = "capital">Nayarit<br>
<INPUT TYPE = "radio" VALUE="cdmx" NAME = "capital" >Ciudad de México<br>
<INPUT TYPE = "radio" VALUE="yucatan" NAME = "capital">Yucatán<br>

2. ¿Cuánto es 9 x 5?<br>
<INPUT TYPE = "radio" VALUE="catorce" CHECKED NAME = "operacion">14<br>
<INPUT TYPE = "radio" VALUE="setenta" NAME = "operacion">70<br>
<INPUT TYPE = "radio" VALUE="cuarentacinco" NAME = "operacion">45<br>

3. ¿Cuántos colores tiene un arcoiris?<br>
<INPUT TYPE = "radio" VALUE="siete" CHECKED NAME = "color">7<br>
<INPUT TYPE = "radio" VALUE="nueve" NAME = "color">9<br>
<INPUT TYPE = "radio" VALUE="ocho" NAME = "color">8<br>

<INPUT TYPE = "submit" VALUE = "Aceptar" NAME= "aceptar"/>
</FORM>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

And this PHP code:

```
<?php

$capital= "";
$operacion = "";
$color = "";
   if($capital == "cdmx") {
       echo"Respuesta 1: Correcto!<br>";
   } else{
       echo"Respuesta 1: Incorrecto!<br>";
   }
   if($operacion == "cuarentacinco"){
       echo"Respuesta 2: Correcto!<br>";
   } else{
       echo"Respuesta 2: Incorrecto!<br>";
   }
       if($color == "siete"){
       echo"Respuesta 3: Correcto!<br>";
   } else{
       echo"Respuesta 3: Incorrecto!<br>";
   }

?>
```

It is supposed to print "Respuesta 1: Correcto!" when you check te correct answer, but for the 3 echo's it writes the false way that is "Respuesta 1: Correcto!", I think that html isn't sending the variables that are checked to the php code, i assure myself that the PHP file is called "respuestas.php", so I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you set $capital? It looks like you're always setting it to "".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the answers,  there is an issue with your form.  Change the method attribute to method ="post"
It might be a typo from your side but please verify

Answer (score 0):

You have to get post values from $_POST array.

```
$capital= $_POST['capital'];
$operacion = $_POST['operacion'];
$color = $_POST['color'];
```